# How to POST login info and then GET lander using cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, post, https, get

I am submitting login form data using curl in php, and from what I've observed the login POST has no response - the lander page is loaded by a subsequent GET request. What I'd like to know is how I can make a POST using curl and then a GET? For reference, here's my current code:

```
    $ch = curl_init('https://<my url>');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: text/html',
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'my post fields');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // I need to make a get request to get the loggedin page here!?
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https:<another_url>');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo curl_errno($ch);
```

I'm currently getting an error 52 from my POST which is no response, which I think should be expected. The issue is, when I tried to make a GET, I also got errno 52. Also for a sanity check, I retrieved my post fields my grabbing the form data from the network data from chrome dev tools.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: lots of sites block automated logins like this, it could be an issue here

Comment: Well, have you actually _tried_ just making a subsequent GET request after the POST?  Or do you not know the page to load?

Comment: Yea, I have. I figured the lack of response from the POST was fine, but I'm also getting no response from my GET. That's why I was hoping someone would potentially share a good way to do this.

Comment: Well, you should include the code for your attempt of the GET request.  What you've provided above only shows one request, the POST.

Comment: Done. Please see my edits.

Comment: I believe curl only writes cookies when you close the connection.  So if cookies are important to the remote system (and there's probably a good chance of that), and they're _not_ session cookies (curl doesn't write those), then I'm pretty sure you need to close the connection after the POST and open a new one for the GET.